# Создать триггер в SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Препод задал сделать на паре (как доп. задание) **триггер, который считает кол-во студентов по регионам и записывает это в другую таблицу**. Я создал представление, которое показывает, какой примерно вывод мы получим в той таблице:

```
SELECT        dbo.Regions.Region, COUNT(dbo.Students.ID) AS Expr1
FROM            dbo.Students INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Regions ON dbo.Students.Region = dbo.Regions.ID
GROUP BY dbo.Regions.Region, dbo.Students.Region
```

Вывод:
`Белгородская область  3`
`Тверская область  2`

Триггер должен работать на основе таблицы Students. Листинг таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateBorn] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Region] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Nationality] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Group] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Groups] FOREIGN KEY([Group])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Groups]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Nationalities] FOREIGN KEY([Nationality])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Nationalities] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Nationalities]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Regions] FOREIGN KEY([Region])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Regions] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Regions]
GO
```

Листинг таблицы Regions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Regions](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Regions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: *как это реализовать.* Читаем, изучаем, понимаем [CREATE TRIGGER](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Потом пишем. Очевидно, что `action = AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`, а действие - `UPDATE Regions ... FROM SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students ...`

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. Я написал, что триггер должен работать только на insert. То есть FROM Inserted.  Или так не получится?

Comment: Не, получится, конечно... но одними инсертами работа с данными не ограничивается. Если запись будет изменена или удалена, статистика станет неактуальной... впрочем, если пофиг, то пусть будет чисто AFTER UPDATE. *То есть FROM Inserted* Именно так. Из неё извлечёшь список регионов, в которые был добавлен хотя бы один студент. Используя этот список, агрегируешь вторую копию Students, считаешь количество студентов в этих регионах после вставки, и обновляешь Regions.

Comment: Ага, понял. А чтобы все это поместить в другую таблицу INSERT INTO KolvoStudentsOnRegions (Kolvo_Students, Region_Name), где Kolvo_Students = int, а Region_Name = nvchar(50), то как это сделать? Просто получаю кучу ошибок

Comment: А при чём тут вообще INSERT? и что за зверёк это `KolvoStudentsOnRegions`?

Comment: Зверек этот отдельная таблица, в которую теперь хочет препод передать все информацию при например ВСТАВКЕ нового студента или нового региона

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_students_amount
ON students
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE regions
SET regions.students_amount = data.students_amount
FROM ( SELECT students.region_id, COUNT(*) students_amount
       FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT region_id
              FROM inserted ) AS updated_regions
       JOIN students ON students.region_id = updated_regions.region_id
       GROUP BY students.region_id ) data
WHERE regions.region_id = data.region_id;
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ada53c53f6867a641ea7b3cda56be47)